# Is there any way to load a controller from a file into ui-router $stateProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Javascript example:

```
$stateProvider.state("stateA",{
            url:"^/statea",
            resolve:{
                //include or importing controller file here 
            },
            views:{
                "header":{
                    templateUrl:"templates/blocks/login/header.html",
                    //OR
                    controllerUrl: "/pathCtrl",
                    controller: nameController

                    }
                }
            }
    });
```

I'd like to be able to import controllers at fly when I need, without be forced to include them into the index file.

Comment: Use build system to bundle all files at build time. You will hardly gain anything worthwhile from keeping the things asynchronous. Angular is very hostile towards lazy loading.

Comment: I agree with estus' comment, but you might be able to use controllerProvider to accomplish this.

Comment: So what the best practice? Shall I have to load all the controllers in one go, when the user lands to any page of my website/webapp?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with eval and $injector service, but I would not recommend it. But here you go:

```
eval(someFileContent);
var someCtrl = $injector.instantiate(SomeCtrlConstructor, {
  $scope: $scope
});
```

Where SomeCtrlConstructor is name of constructor created by eval. There some problem with this solution. Most prominent of them is use of this. You could pass this to child component as self. Just as with $scope.

var someCtrl = $injector.instantiate(SomeCtrlConstructor, {
  $scope: $scope,
  self: this
});

working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y552xgo7/

Comment: So what would you recommend about loading controllers dinamically?
Let's say we have 50 controllers, what in this case?

Comment: Depends what do you need that for. But take a look at webpack 2 and dynamic module loading. Or some other module system.